# Keycloak can't verify the JWT from my flutter openid client

Tags: flutter, keycloak, openid-connect, openid, keycloak-connect

In my Flutter app, I use the *openid_client* library to authorize myself with a keycloak instance and get an access token.
For testing purposes, I tried the node js server example of keycloak (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-nodejs) to verify my access token from the flutter app, but everytime I try, I get an "access denied" error.

If I try it with the javascript frontend example from keycloak (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-nodejs-html5) it works with the same keycloak user and client.

I compared the two different tokens and the only thing I noticed is that the keycloak example has an additional "nonce" field (and the "iss" is different).

What could I have missed, which is why the token from the flutter app does not work?